# How to count instances in a pandas dataframe based on two parameters (using a lambda function with an 'and' operator)?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to determine the number of instances in my dataframe that are both 'Pentioners' and have 'Days employed' = 365243. I can obtain the count of either 'Pensioners' or 'Days employed' seperately, but not the combined requirement.

This function works correctly:

```
number_pensioners = app_train.apply(lambda x: True if x['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] == 'Pensioner' else False, axis = 1
                                   )
numRows = len(number_pensioners[number_pensioners == True].index)
```

However this function returns and error:

```
number_pensioners = app_train.apply(lambda x: True if x['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] == 'Pensioner' & x['DAYS_EMPLOYED'] == 365243 else False, axis = 1
                                   )
numRows = len(number_pensioners[number_pensioners == True].index)
```

The error returned is:

```
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: USE 'AND' INSTEAD OF '&' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `and` instead `&`, because processing scalars:

```
number_pensioners = app_train.apply(lambda x: True if (x['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] == 'Pensioner') and (x['DAYS_EMPLOYED'] == 365243) else False, axis = 1
                                   )
numRows = len(number_pensioners[number_pensioners == True].index)
```

But better/ faster is vectorized solution with all columns with `&` and paratheses for mask:

```
m = (app_train['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] == 'Pensioner') & (app_train['DAYS_EMPLOYED'] == 365243)
```

And then count `True`s by `sum`:

```
print (m.sum())
```

Or get length of filtered rows:

```
print (len(number_pensioners[m]))
```

Comment: Great, that worked! I tried both and they work, and your statement on the speed was confirmed, the vectorized solution is much faster than the first method. Thanks jezrael.